# Reading an article using fgets and printf it out

Tags: c

I want to the program read an article and print it out
But when I input any sentence it doesn't output anything.
How to solve this problem?
Here is my code snippet.

```
char line[1001], article[1001];

fprintf(stderr, "Enter the article: ");

while( fgets(line, string_len, stdin)!=NULL){
    strcat(article, line);

    int line_num = 0;
    line_num = strlen(line);
    for(int j = 0; j < line_num; j++){
        line[j] = '\0';
    }
} 
printf("article:%s\n",article);
```

Comment: What is the value of `string_len`? It must be set before reading. Check [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: `strcat(article, line);` will likely overflow `char article[1001];`

Comment: Also, resetting `line[]` is redundant `int line_num=0;
   line_num=strlen(line);
   for(int j=0;j<line_num;j++){
       line[j]='\0';`

Comment: You need to send ("type") `EOF` (**Ctrl+D** on Un\*x or **Ctrl+Z** on Windows) to signal "end of article"

Comment: Please take some time to read the [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As your question stands now the code is not compile-able.

Comment: You need to initialise `article` before you can concatenate. And I suggest sth like `char article[100000] = "";`. Aside please don't use `stderr` for normal output.